# Twitter API issues.“Authentication needed”"Failed to validate oauth signature and token"

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter

I have a question, and I have googled it, but I didn't find the answer.

I create an iOS twitter app,and apply for a twitter API.
I used my API key in my app, Xcode returns error.
Just like this: http://tinypic.com/r/262ksnk/8
("Failed to validate oauth signature and token")

and this picture is my Twitter API status
(sorry,I do not have enough coin to upload a pic,so post my pic [here](http://tinypic.com/r/ifd8jq/8). )

What is wrong with my Twitter API, can anyone help me?

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This error message relates to a HTTP 401 response.

Please make sure you are properly signing your OAuth requests. This guide will help you with the common pitfalls: [Troubleshooting OAuth 1.0A](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/204).

In particular, if you are using valid keys and properly signing your OAuth requests but still receiving 401 errors, please check your system time. Since the OAuth signature relies on the current time, it must be in sync with the one from Twitter servers (exposed in all `Date` response headers from the Twitter API).

Answer (score 0):

The "performance issues" described on the [Twitter API status page](https://dev.twitter.com/status) apply to Twitter as a whole, and have nothing to do with your application. If you are having issues interacting with the Twitter API, we cannot diagnose those from the information provided ("error 3").